# How can I determine the latest released firmware for my Samsung device?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, device-firmware

This problem eludes me. I have two Samsung Android devices, a Galaxy Tab 10.1 and a Galaxy S2. I keep'em up-to-date using the update option in the settings panel, however, I think I'm not always sporting the newest firmware that was released, maybe because of region issues or some other reason.

So I would like to know if there's a Samsung website or any other source where I can spot the latest stock firmware available?

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

In general there really doesn't seem to be a good way to keep up with updates that haven't been released directly to you.  I find the best way is simply to be involved in the "Android ecosystem" — reading Android blogs and news sites, and so on.

Sometimes there are stock ROM lists maintained on sites like XDA, for example [this one for the i9001](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1346245), and you can monitor those.

For actually acquiring ROMs, see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465)

Comment: Thanks! It's too bad Samsung doesn't have that kind of communication with its users. I hope that, as this market matures, the manufacturers get more smart about this kind of thing.